# Unknown erroneous characters are being added to strings?

Tags: c

I am learning C. Some characters are being added automatically to my program. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char test1[2]="xx";
  char test2[2]="xx";
  printf("test is %s and %s.\n", test1, test2);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is how I am running it on Fedora 20.

```
gcc -o problem problem.c
./problem
test is xx?}� and xx@.
```

I would expect the answer would be `test is xx and xx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that string literals such as `"xx"` have an extra character that is the nul-termination, `\0`, that is, it is composed of the characters `'x'`, `'x'` and `'\0'`.

This is how functions that take `char*` and treat them as strings know the extent of the strings. Your arrays are simply one element too short, missing the nul-terminator. By passing `char*` that don't point to a nul-terminated string to a function that expects one, you are invoking *undefined behaviour*.

You can initialize them like this instead:

```
char test[] = "xx";
```

This will result in `test` having the correct length of `3`. You can test that using the `sizeof` operator. Of course, you can also be explicit about the length:

```
char test[3] = "xx";
```

but this is more error-prone.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Am I not suppose to declare the number of characters?

Comment: @donniezazen Yes, you can (see my last edit). But you have to get it right!

Comment: @donniezazen It works, but the RHS really has 4 characters, so you're one short :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you define a String in C like this

```
char A[] = "hello";
```

It gets initialized something like this

```
A = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}
```

That last null character is needed for the it to be a string. So in your code

```
char test1[2]="xx";
```

You have made the `test1` character array to be 2 characters long, leaving no space for the null character.

To correct your program, You can either not give the size of the character array, like

```
char test1[]="xx";
```

Or, give one more then the characters you are filling in, like

```
char test1[3]="xx";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `char test1[2]="xx"`, `char test1[2]` creates a kind a "container" for two chars, but the actual string `"xx"` implicitly has three chars `xx0`, where `0` indicates an end of the line. This 0 is an indicator for printf, where it should stop reading the input string. In your case printf doesn't get this 0 as 0 doesn't fit into the `test1` and it reads to some random zero in memory, printing everything it meets on the way.

You should change your declaration to the following:

```
char test1[3]="xx"
```