# Unusual string concatenation when outputting to printf or to files on C

Tags: c, json, string, struct

I am working for a project developing an agenda, i am using two structures: Contact and Dates (Contacto and Cita respectively):

```
struct Contacto{
 char nombre[15];
 char apellido[20];
 char fechaCump[10];
 char direccion[50];
 char telef[10];
};

typedef struct Contacto Contacto;

struct Cita{
 char fecha[10];
 char lugar[50];
 char horaInicio[5];
 char horaFin[5];
 Contacto *user;
};
typedef struct Cita Cita;
```

On the main file,i am working with jsmn library and a load function (copiarArchivo) to load data from a JSON file, parse it, and copy it to structures:

```
int i;
int r;
jsmn_parser p;
jsmntok_t t[256];
char *js;
char *jsCitas;
Contacto *temp;
Cita *ctemp;
Contacto *conCita;
char nombreBusqueda[15];
char apeBusqueda[20];

js=copiarArchivo("contactos.json");
jsCitas=copiarArchivo("citas.json");    
sizeContactos=0;
sizeCitas=0;

if(js!=NULL){
    jsmn_init(&p);
    r = jsmn_parse(&p, js, strlen(js), t, sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]));
    if (r < 0) {
        printf("Failed to parse JSON: %d\n", r);
    }

    /* Assume the top-level element is an object */
    if (r < 1 || t[0].type != JSMN_OBJECT) {
        printf("Object expected\n");
    }

    for (i = 1; i < r; i++){
        if (jsoneq(js, &t[i], "name") == 0) {           
            temp=malloc(sizeof(Contacto));
            strncpy(temp->nombre,js + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("NAME: %s\n",temp->nombre);          

            i+=2;
            strncpy(temp->apellido,js + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("APELLIDO: %s\n",temp->apellido);            
            i+=2;
            strncpy(temp->fechaCump,js + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("BIRTH: %s\n",temp->fechaCump);          
            i+=2;
            strncpy(temp->telef,js + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("TELF: %s\n",temp->telef);           
            i+=2;
            strncpy(temp->direccion,js + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("DIR: %s\n",temp->direccion);
            insertar(&headContacto, temp);
            sizeContactos++;            
            i++;
            printf("\nEnd of parsed info\n");   
        }
    }
print_list(headContacto);
}
else{
    printf("\nNo se ha podido cargar el archivo de contactos o no hay info guardada\n");
}   

if(jsCitas!=NULL){
    jsmn_init(&p);
    r = jsmn_parse(&p, jsCitas, strlen(jsCitas), t, sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]));
    if (r < 0) {
        printf("Failed to parse JSON: %d\n", r);
    }

    /* Assume the top-level element is an object */
    if (r < 1 || t[0].type != JSMN_OBJECT) {
        printf("Object expected\n");
    }

    for (i = 1; i < r; i++){
        if (jsoneq(jsCitas, &t[i], "fecha") == 0) {
            char fec[10];           
            ctemp=malloc(sizeof(Cita));
            strncpy(ctemp->fecha,jsCitas + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("FECHA: %s\n",ctemp->fecha);
            strcpy(fec,ctemp->fecha);           
            i+=2;
            strncpy(ctemp->lugar,jsCitas + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("LUGAR: %s\n",ctemp->lugar);         
            i+=2;
            strncpy(ctemp->horaInicio,jsCitas + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("INICIO: %s\n",ctemp->horaInicio);           
            i+=2;
            strncpy(ctemp->horaFin,jsCitas + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            printf("FIN: %s\n",ctemp->horaFin);         
            i+=2;
            strncpy(nombreBusqueda,jsCitas + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            i+=2;
            strncpy(apeBusqueda,jsCitas + t[i+1].start,t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start);
            if(*nombreBusqueda && *apeBusqueda){
                conCita=buscarNodo(&headContacto,nombreBusqueda,apeBusqueda);
                if(conCita!=NULL){
                    ctemp->user=conCita;                    
                }
            }
            push(&headCita, ctemp);
            sizeCitas++;            
            i++;
            printf("\nEnd of parsed info\n");   
        }
    }
print_citas(headCita);
}
else{
    printf("\nNo se ha podido cargar el archivo de citas o no hay info guardada\n");
}
```

The problem is when i output some structures members like fechaCump (birth date) to printf function or to files with fprintf, it appears concatenated with direccion (address) member, and the same problem is with fecha (date) concatenated with lugar (date address) on Cita struct.
[Here I put a screen capture that shows this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkPWJ.png) and [a capture of the JSON structure of Contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDJAM.png)

My question is why does this behavior happen and how could I solve it?
Below i left the code to load file:

```
char *copiarArchivo(const char *name){
 char *buffer = NULL;
 size_t size = 0;

 /* Open your_file in read-only mode */
 FILE *fp = fopen(name, "r");

 if(fp==NULL){
     return buffer; 
 }
 /* Get the buffer size */
 fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); /* Go to end of file */
 size = ftell(fp); /* How many bytes did we pass ? */

 if(size==0){
     return buffer; 
 }
 /* Set position of stream to the beginning */
 rewind(fp);

 /* Allocate the buffer (no need to initialize it with calloc) */
 buffer = malloc((size) * sizeof(*buffer)); /* size + 1 byte for the \0 */

 /* Read the file into the buffer */
 fread(buffer, size, 1, fp);
 return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown erroneous characters are being added to strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347921/unknown-erroneous-characters-are-being-added-to-strings)

Comment: Please always provide text content as text in your question. No need to include screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fechaCump[10]` has space for 10 chars (really 9 + the NUL terminator). "16/02/1996" is 10 chars. That means there is no space for your terminating 0 character. You need to make `fechaCump` (and perhaps some of the other fields) longer so they can for the NUL terminator in.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I forgot that, this works perfect on my project